# How to export constants defined using object destructuring

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, eslint, es6-modules

Guided by eslint's [prefer-destructuring](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring) rule, I defined some constants like this:

```
const {
    NODE_ENV,
    API_URL,
} = process.env;
```

Is it possible to export these constants by prefixing the statement by `export`?

```
export const {
    NODE_ENV,
    API_URL,
} = process.env;
```

This would seem natural, but [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import) complains about a violation of the [import/named](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/named.md) rule: `API_URL not found in '../constants'`. In fact, this usage of `export` is also not described on the relevant [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

Do we then have to repeat all constants in a separate `export` statement?

```
const {
    NODE_ENV,
    API_URL,
} = process.env;

export {
    NODE_ENV,
    API_URL,
};
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, that question has nothing to do with it. OP wants syntax for named exports, not build another object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to export these constants by prefixing the statement by
>   `export`?
>
> ```
> export const {
>     NODE_ENV,
>     API_URL,
> } = process.env;
> ```

Yes, this is totally valid according to the spec. You can use destructuring patterns in the declarations of exported `const`s.

> This would seem natural, but
>   [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import)
>   complains about a violation of the
>   [import/named](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/named.md)
>   rule: `API_URL not found in '../constants'`.

Sounds like that plugin is broken. In fact, your exact use case [was reported as working](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/718) before.

Comment: You're entirely right, this problem is triggered by a bug in eslint-plugin-import, reported in issue [#718](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/718), and fixed in PR [#1232](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/pull/1232). The bug occurs only when the export uses destructuring with default values. I had edited the default values out of my question because I thought they were not relevant.

Comment: @Claudio So does it work now after an update to the latest version, or did they break again what they fixed in #1232?

Comment: I believe #1232 is not released yet.

Answer (score 2):

Article 15.2.2.3 of the spec says:

> ```
>  ...
> ExportDeclaration : export VariableStatement
> ExportDeclaration : export Declaration
> ```

Article 13.1.4 says:

> ```
> Declaration : LexicalDeclaration
> ```

Article 13.3 says:

> ```
> LexicalDeclaration:
>    LetOrConst BindingList;
>
> LetOrConst :
>  let
>  const
>
> BindingList :
>  LexicalBinding
>  BindingList, LexicalBinding
>
>  LexicalBinding:
>   BindingPattern Initializer
> ```

Therefore this:

```
 // ExportDeclaration
  export  // export
    // Declaration
    // LexicalDeclaration:
    const // LetOrConst
     // LexicalBindingList
     // LexicalBinding
     { NODE_ENV, API_URL } // BindingPattern
      = process.env; // Initializer
```

is totally valid JavaScript.

Comment: Aye, that's what I found too!